# C# add XMLNode to XMLNodeList

Tags: c#, xml

This one I thought would be simple, but i really just have 1 node I need to add to a node List.

So I have `XmlNode xmlNode`.  This node has all the information I need in it.  I need to add this to `XmlNodeList xmlnodeList`.  I know this is dumb because it's not a list, but the following code has all the parts to handle a node list and would be a pain to unwind.

Also normally I would use `XmlNodeList xmlnodeList = xmlNode.FirstChild.SelectNodes` however i need this entire node, not just the childnodes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about:

```
XmlNodeList xmlNodeList = xmlNode.SelectNodes(".");
```

Comment: I love it when its just a simple answer, ty